# Can we call a variable from the class below the other class in Python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I was wondering if there is a method of calling a variable from another class below from the above without switching its position.

```
class First(Second, Third):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.num1 = 1

    # add num
    def add_nums(self):
        print(self.num1 + self.set_num2() + self.set_num3()) 

#Second class
class Second:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num2 = 2

    # Set num
    def set_num2(self):
        return self.num2

# Third class
class Third:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num3 = 3
    
    def set_num3(self):
        return self.num3
```

On the above, without changing the position of classes, is there a way to call the second and third class function output.

Comment: No, this is not :)

Comment: It's not the variable or functions defined later: you can't even define `First`, since `Second` and `Third` are not defined at the point (assuming this is all in one file). Try it. Just put `First` at the bottom, so that `Second` are `Third` are defined when `First(Second, Third)` is defined.

Comment: The problem is probably that *all* classes need to include `super().__init__()` for `super` to do its job properly, otherwise one of the parents won’t be initialized.

Comment: Surprisingly, if you remove the Third class and its inheritance from the 'First' class, it works without super() and without changing the order.

Comment: I tested and by removing the third, it does not work either in my environment.